# ADT plug-in just updated but Eclipse still complaining

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have a fully working project in Eclipse Juno.  I imported the exact same project to Eclipse Neon (Release 4.6.2).  Unfortunately Neon is reporting 100's of errors in the very same project.  That includes the error on layouts that the ADT plug-in must be updated.  I just confirmed:

- ADT version 23.0.7.2120684 is installed in Eclipse Neon
- Android 7.1.1 (API 25) is installed in the SDK Manager

I must be missing something obvious.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!